# Get users names by their ids

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to find user name by user id like this:

```
FB.api('/' + userId, .....)
```

but I get error that I need access token.

I tried passing it like this:

```
FB.api('/' + userId + '?access_token=' + FB.getAuthResponse(), ...)
```

but this time I got 'invalid token' error.

Is this (obtaining other user's names by their ids) possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a User Token for the ID. You can just forget about the ID in the API call and use `/me` instead:

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'id,name'}, (response) => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Btw, you do not need to add the Access Token in your API call, the JavaScript SDK handles that for you. Just use `FB.login` to authorize your User.

For example: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Btw, getting data of users who did not authorize your App is not possible at all, for privacy reasons.

Comment: Hi luschn and thanks for the answer. The problem is that I don't need mine, I need to find name of an arbitrary user by his/hers id.

Comment: is the user authorized in your app? how did you get the id?

Comment: Maybe my workflow is totally wrong. So I have simple web app supporting only FB login, When the user is logged and posts something, its ID is stored in the DB along the post. When someone else or nobody is logged in, I need to display the user names, not IDs, of the previous posts. I suppose that I could store the username along the user ID in the DB, but thought extracting the username by userid would be much simpler (it turned out it is not).

Comment: you don´t even get the username anymore since v2.0. just use the (app scoped) user id for identification.

Comment: Identification is fine but I need to show more user-friendly id/name/etc (the ID that I have is like 1234567890) Could I somehow get whatever more user-friendly info?